# Java: is this necessary while catching exception?

Tags: java, exception

eWhile catching exceptions is this necessary to check if the error message is not null to avoid null pointer exception? Another words, is the if (e!=null) part needed? or e is always not null?

```
 try {
     ...

  } catch(Exception e) {
     if (e != null) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
     }

  }
```

Comment: `e` **can't** be null, but `e.getMessage()` can be.

Comment: you don't have add null check for e but methods inherited from super class Throwable could still return null. For example, getMessage -> returns null. This happens during NullPointerException. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anything that gets thrown must be a subclass of `Throwable`, and your catch will only catch things that are a subclass of `Exception`. Therefore you can neither throw nor catch `null`, therefore checking for nullality is not necessary. If you use `throw null` or throw a variable that contains null then it will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: +1 Indeed, without to mention that the catch itself should throw an exception in that case...

Comment: It must be a Throwable, but doesn't necessarily have to be a subclass of Exception. But it's true in this context, since it is trying to catch Exception. +1 Anyway.

Comment: +1 for inventing the word `nullality`!! Makes a refreshing change from `nullness` and `nullity` and ... of course ... er ... `null`. :)

Answer (score 3):

The exception will never be null. However, some properties of the exception could be null.

Answer (score 3):

`e` will never be null.  Even if you `throw null` (which is perfectly legal) java will convert that into a `NullPointerException` as detailed in the spec [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.18)

Answer (score 1):

The caught exception will never be `null` as it is been already caught. So the check:

```
if (e != null) { }
```

Is absolutely not necessary.